# Proguard issue when enabling it

Tags: android, proguard

```
Proguard  returned with error code 1. See console  
Warning: com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAdView: can't find referenced       method 'FrameLayout(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int,int)'   in class android.widget.FrameLayout  
     You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.  
     Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.  
     Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.  
     You may need to recompile them and try again.  
     Alternatively, you may have to specify the option   
     '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.  
    java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.  
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)  
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)  
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)  
    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the Project Build Target from Android 4.4.2 to Android 5.1.1 and then the problem does not happen again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i lost that one but got this one instead: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhu: can't find referenced class android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy